# Batch File to delete files last accessed or created, older than X days

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm looking to end my batch scripting code in order to delete accdb files older than 7 days, the code that I have already deletes files, but  it takes "Last Modification Date" I need to change this to "Last Accessed Date" or "Creation Date".

is there a way to do it in a Bat File or should I move to PowerShell?

[image: Access Database Dates - Example]

Batch Code:

```
forfiles /P O:\Backup\ /S /M *.accdb /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @PATH"
```

I've already read similar questions but I didn't figure it out.

Comment: "Last Accessed Date" or "Creation Date"…Which?

Comment: From a command prompt, `forfiles /?` tells you what is possible.

Comment: So what is your question? You obviously must know that `FORFILES` only uses the modified date if you read the help file.  So what is your expectation?

Comment: Windows doesn't use Last Access anymore for speed reasons. See `fsutil behavior query disablelastaccess`.

Comment: @Squashman I'm asking here so I "must not" know the answer... if you don't have the answer please don't answer anything else ;) thx

Comment: @Rokrman22, StackOverFlow was created as a Question and Answer site for code related problems.  You have not asked a question.  `FORFILES` only uses modified date so you will have to come up with some different code you need help with that doesn't use modified date to select the files.

Comment: @Compo Last Accessed Date would be better, but Creation date is the same as I'm re creating the file and creation/accessed is the same date. thanks

Comment: @Squashman if you didn't understand the question you can read it again. Sayonara

Comment: @CatCat thanks I'll check it out , may be I move to powershell in this case... thanks everyone!

Comment: `ForFiles` uses the modification date, so you'll need to use one or more alternative commands. Please read the comments above by @Squashman, they are intended to teach you that you are supposed to provide you code which was written to do something specific but doesn't, and that you have not asked a question. You have not attempted the task yourself; if you don't make any effort, it doesn't motivate others to make any effort to help you. Please search on how to perform the task you need, write your code and [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51563787/edit) accordingly.

Comment: @Compo don't really catch you, first I put my batch code and i said "I need to change my code to get last accessed or creation date" it's really clear to my and very easy, the answer was also easy, there are no easy way to do it in batch file as forfiles get last modified date... I move to powershell and It worked just fine.

Comment: by the way poweshell code for everyone that could help:
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
Thanks anyway

Comment: Based upon your newly edited questions, 1. Yes there's 'a way to do it in a Bat File'. 2. If you wish to 'move to PowerShell', then do so. The previous comments I made still stand, it is your responsibility to research and create the code, ours is to help you fix it. You still have not attempted to do it without `ForFiles` or `PowerShell`, until you do so, your question is unclear and a code request and remains off topic.

Comment: @Compo haha you make me laugh a lot man! 1) So if your responsability is "help me to fix my code" you failed quite a lot right? 2) I moved to PS because first, I don't have brain limits to get caught with one scripting code as you DO. I can get another different code to my solution, so it doesn't matter if you can't think outside of the box bro, I've watched a lot of questions answered correctly in this way 3) the question still unclear??? WOW hahaha you have problems, the key here is to give a good answer but first understand a symple question, start with the first thing then we can talk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move to powershell and it worked just fine:

$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$path = "C:\Users\Test1"

Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$*.PSIsContainer -and $*.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force

Delete any empty directories left behind after deleting the old files.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $*.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $*.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
Read-Host -Prompt "Backup Processed Succesfully - Press Enter to exit"